# if URL is only at base URL then redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below is not executing and the console is outputting `undefined`. I am simply trying to run a *redirect* `if` the user is ***at*** the homepage or base URL only; currently the console is not giving any errors, just throwing `undefined` and the redirect *doesn't* execute regardless if homepage or not. I am not trying to use if url contains or similar; I think I need to check for absolute URL as there is no suffix (ie. `#page` or `/page.htm` etc)

```
var homepage = "http://www.website.com";
var current = window.location.href;

if(current == homepage) { // I have tried both == and ===
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "http://www.website.com/navi/"; 
    }, 2000);   
}
```

Comment: Add a console.log(current); to check the value. Maybe you're missing somehing like "https" instead of "http" or "http: //www.website.com/" (with slash at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

location has several useful variables like:

```
{
  "href": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835282/if-url-is-only-at-base-url-then-redirect",
  "ancestorOrigins": {},
  "origin": "https://stackoverflow.com",
  "protocol": "https:",
  "host": "stackoverflow.com",
  "hostname": "stackoverflow.com",
  "port": "",
  "pathname": "/questions/49835282/if-url-is-only-at-base-url-then-redirect",
  "search": "",
  "hash": ""
}
```

if you look close at that, you could literarily check if
`location.pathname == "/" && location.hash == ""`
to check if you are on the base url without a hash.

Comment: such downvote. at least provide feedback for improvement.